# How to use decorators and functions with Flask blueprints

Tags: python, flask

I have a pre-existing Flask application which is becoming quite large, so I've decided to switch to using blueprints, following the Flask documentation, to organise my views.

Most of my views share functions and decorators. When all my views were in one file, it was easy to access them. How now all the views are organised into separate files, I'm unsure where to locate information such as functions and views.

I have the following file structure:

```
run.py
website/
  __init__.py
  views/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    home.py
    ...
  templates/
  static/
```

So, where do I locate functions and decorators and how do I access them? Thanks.

Comment: This large flask project has a good layout, take a look. https://github.com/masom/bluemonk

Comment: @CaptainMurphy I've just looked through the project and found no solution to the probem.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question. You want to know how to put functions somewhere and import them?

Comment: Yes I would like to know where to put them and how to access them. But not only functions, but custom decorators also.

Comment: A decorator is imported the same way as a function. Just make submodule of your functiosn and import from it. `website.py/myfuncs.py`. `from website.myfuncs import awesomefunction`

Comment: So say a decorator is called `@authenticate` in myfuncs.py, I would import it like `from myfuncs.py import authenticate` and the decorator can be used?

Comment: Yes, `from myfuncs import authenticate` (no .py). Also my previous comment should have had the folder, no .py there either. `website/myfuncs.py`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any code that is shared by two or more blueprints can be put in separate modules. So for example, you can have `decorators.py` and `functions.py`, which can be located inside your `views` directory:

```
run.py
website/
  __init__.py
  views/
    __init__.py
    decorators.py   # <-- common code
    functions.py    # <-- common code
    admin.py
    home.py
    ...
  templates/
  static/
```

Then in your views you can import elements from these as follows:

```
from .decorators import my_decorator
```

If there's other code in other directories besides `views` that might need these common elements (such as a `forms` directory for Flask-WTF forms, for example), then you can put your common modules one level up in `website`.

```
run.py
website/
  __init__.py
  decorators.py   # <-- common code
  functions.py    # <-- common code
  views/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    home.py
    ...
  templates/
  static/
```

And with this structure you can import from your views as follows:

```
from ..decorators import my_decorator
```

or:

```
from website.decorators import my_decorator
```

You can see an example of the above structure in the [Flasky](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky) application that is featured in my Flask Web Development book. I have `decorators.py`, `email.py` and `exceptions.py` as common modules that can be accessed by all the blueprints.

If the number of common modules is large, you can also move the common modules inside their own package:

```
run.py
website/
  __init__.py
  common/
    __init__.py
    decorators.py
    functions.py
  views/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    home.py
    ...
  templates/
  static/
```

And then the imports look like this:

```
from ..common.decorators import my_decorator
```

or:

```
from website.common.decorators import my_decorator
```